# For every possible pair of two unique words in the file, print out the count of occurrences of that pair

Tags: c, unix, word-count

this code works for single word counts and it differentiate between words with punctuation words with upper lower case. Is there an easy way around to make this code work for pairs as well instead of single words? like I need to print the occurrence of every pair of words in a text file.
Your help is much appreciated,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
FILE* f = fopen (argv[1], "r");
char buffer[10000];
if (argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);

}
fclose(f);
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "tr -cs '[:punct:][a-z][A-Z]'   '[\\n*]' < %s |"
                                 " sort | uniq -c | sort -n", argv[1]);

return(system(buffer));
}
```

Example input

```
 The Cat Sat On The Mat
```

Output
     (The Cat, The Sat, The On, The The, The Mat, Cat The, Cat Sat, Cat On, for 30 pairs)

Comment: Huh! "In C"? Why didn't you type in that command directly?

Comment: @weather vane edit it

Comment: Is this an assignment? Are you sure you are allowed to just use `system` to call external tools? Assignments usually require you to implement the actual functionality without invoking other programs.

Comment: yes it is an assignment. I asked my TA and it should be fine!

Comment: What do you consider a `pair` of words? Adjacent? Delimited? What?

Comment: Please edit the input and expected output into the question, where you can format the data for legibility.  Are you looking for adjacent word pairs?  That is, with `The Cat Sat On The Mat`, you have 5 pairs (`The Cat`, `Cat Sat`,`Sat On`, `On The`, `The Mat`), or are you looking for all possible word pairs (`The Cat`, `The Sat`, `The On`, `The The`, `The Mat`, `Cat The`, `Cat Sat`, `Cat On`, for 30 pairs), or some other definition?

Comment: Jonathan. I did edit my post. You are correct. It should be for every possible pair and so the occurrence of some pairs will be zero. Also note that it has to be unique words, so we cant say "the the" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems inconceivable that the purpose of your assignment determining the frequency of word-pairs in a file would be to have you wrap a piped-string of shell utilities in a `system` call. What does that possibly teach you about C? That a `system` function exists that allows shell access? Well, it does, and you can, lesson done, nothing learned.

It seems far more likely that the intent was for you to understand the use of *structures* to hold collections of related data in a single object, or at the minimum *array* or *pointer indexing* to check for pairs in adjacent words within a file. Of the 2 normal approaches, use of a struct, or index arithmetic, the use of a struct is far more beneficial. Something simple to hold a pair of words and the frequency that pair is seen is all you need. e.g.:

```
enum { MAXC = 32, MAXP = 100 };

typedef struct {
    char w1[MAXC];
    char w2[MAXC];
    size_t freq;
} wordpair;
```

(note, the `enum` simply defines the constants `MAXC` (`32`) and `MAXP` (`100`) for maximum characters per-word, and maximum pairs to record. You could use two `#define` statements to the same end)

You can declare an array of the `wordpair` struct which will hold a pair or words `w1` and `w2` and how many time that pair is seen in `freq`. The array of struct can be treated like any other array, sorted, etc..

To analyze the file, you simply need to read the first two words into the first struct, save a pointer to the second word, and then read each remaining word that remains in the file comparing whether the pair formed by the pointer and the new word read already exists (if so simply update the number of times seen), and if it doesn't exist, add a new pair updating the pointer to point to the new word read, and repeat.

Below is a short example that will check the pair occurrence for the words in all filenames given as arguments on the command line (e.g. `./progname file1 file2 ...`). If no file is given, the code will read from `stdin` by default.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 32, MAXP = 100 };

typedef struct {
    char w1[MAXC];
    char w2[MAXC];
    size_t freq;
} wordpair;

size_t get_pair_freq (wordpair *words, FILE *fp);
int compare (const void *a, const void *b);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* initialize variables & open file or stdin for seening */
    wordpair words[MAXP] = {{"", "", 0}};
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read from file given, or from stdin (default) */
    idx = get_pair_freq (words, stdin);

    /* read each remaining file given on command line */
    for (i = 2; i < (size_t)argc; i++)
    {   if (fp && fp != stdin) { fclose (fp); fp = NULL; }
        /* open file for reading */
        if (!(fp = fopen (argv[i], "r"))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                        argv[i]);
            continue;
        }

        /* check 'idx' against MAXP */
        if ((idx += get_pair_freq (words, fp)) == MAXP)
            break;
    }
    if (fp && fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    /* sort words alphabetically */
    qsort (words, idx, sizeof *words, compare);

    /* output the frequency of word pairs */
    printf ("\nthe occurrence of words pairs are:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        char pair[MAXC * 2] = "";
        sprintf (pair, "%s:%s", words[i].w1, words[i].w2);
        printf ("  %-32s : %zu\n", pair, words[i].freq);
    }

    return 0;
}

size_t get_pair_freq (wordpair *pairs, FILE *fp)
{
    char w1[MAXC] = "", w2[MAXC] = "";
    char *fmt1 = " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c";
    char *fmt2 = " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*[^A-Za-z0-9]%32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c";
    char *w1p;
    int nw = 0;
    size_t i, idx = 0;

    /* read 1st 2 words into pair, update index 'idx' */
    if (idx == 0) {
        if ((nw = fscanf (fp, fmt2, w1, w2)) == 2) {
            strcpy (pairs[idx].w1, w1);
            strcpy (pairs[idx].w2, w2);
            pairs[idx].freq++;
            w1p = pairs[idx].w2;    /* save pointer to w2 for next w1 */
            idx++;
        }
        else {
            if (!nw) fprintf (stderr, "error: file read error.\n");
            return idx;
        }
    }

    /* read each word in file into w2 */
    while (fscanf (fp, fmt1, w2) == 1) {
        /* check against all pairs in struct */
        for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
            /* check if pair already exists  */
            if (strcmp (pairs[i].w1, w1p) == 0 && 
                strcmp (pairs[i].w2, w2) == 0) {
                pairs[i].freq++;    /* update frequency for pair  */
                goto skipdup;       /* skip adding duplicate pair */
            }
        } /* add new pair, update pairs[*idx].freq */
        strcpy (pairs[idx].w1, w1p);
        strcpy (pairs[idx].w2, w2);
        pairs[idx].freq++;
        w1p = pairs[idx].w2;
        idx++;

    skipdup:

        if (idx == MAXP) { /* check 'idx' against MAXP */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXP words exceeded.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return idx;
}

/* qsort compare funciton */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (strcmp (((wordpair *)a)->w1, ((wordpair *)b)->w1));
}
```

**Use/Output**

Given your example of `"Hi how are you are you."`, it produces the desired results (in sorted order according to your `LOCALE`).

```
$ echo "Hi how are you are you." | ./bin/file_word_pairs

the occurrence of words pairs are:

  Hi:how                           : 1
  are:you                          : 2
  how:are                          : 1
  you:are                          : 1
```

(there is no requirement that you sort the results, but it makes lookup/confirmation a lot easier with longer files)

**Removing qsort**

```
$ echo "Hi how are you are you." | ./bin/file_word_pairs

the occurrence of words pairs are:

  Hi:how                           : 1
  how:are                          : 1
  are:you                          : 2
  you:are                          : 1
```

While you are free to attempt to use your `system` version, why not take the time to learn how to approach the problem in C. If you want to learn how to do it through a `system` call, take a `Linux` course, as doing it in that manner has very little to do with C.

Look it over, lookup the functions that are new to you in the *man pages* and then ask about anything you don't understand thereafter.

Comment: Much appreciated David! I am just trying to compile the program gcc program.c then ./a.out words_file.txt but it doesnt work, any suggestions ?

Comment: Sure `gcc -Wall -Wextra filename.c`  That will produce `a.out`. Then just `./a.out filename` to read pairs in `filename`. You can also add `-o` to your compile and give your executable a real name, e.g.  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o myexename filename.c` and that will create `myexename` as your executable.

Comment: I used : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -o bin/file_word_pairs file_word_pairs.c` which just added the `-Ofast` optimization.

Comment: I am getting an error that -Wall and -Wextra are unrecognized command lines

Comment: Those are basic flags to *enable compiler warnings*. You can omit them. `gcc filename.c` is enough. If you are having problems with `-Wall -Werror`, then you are not on Linux, and you need to read the help on whatever IDE you are using to locate the correct place for setting compiler options. `-Wall -Werror` are basic `gcc` flags that should be part of *every* compile (especially for new C users). Whenever you have option questions, just `man gcc` then `/searchterm` to find `searchterm` in the man page. It's looks like Greek at first, but it is good information.